# Ignoring initial loading of PHP_SELF

Tags: php, html, post

I am learning PHP and I have a page that reloads back to itself. I want to know if you can ignore a certain function on the initial loading of the page and only call it once the form submit button has been clicked.

The page is passed a 'ticketID' and loads the information from it. I then want to be able to add a note using the following form method:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<strong>Add Note:</strong> 
<textarea name="note" rows="5" cols="40" value=><?php echo htmlspecialchars($note);?></textarea>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $noteErr;?></span><br>
```

The user then clicks on a submit button to submit the note for processing:

```
<button type='submit' name='ticketID' value= <?php echo $_POST['ticketID'];?> >View</button>
</form>
```

The 'ticketID' is then passed back to the page to reload the information.

If the submit button is pressed and no note has been entered I want a message box to display informing the user to include a note. I have tried:

```
if (!empty($_POST["note"])) 
    {
    echo "This has updated...";
    } else {
    echo "Missing!";
    }
```

However this loads the error message even on the initial load of the page. I have tried setting a variable to the POST ticketID value and clearing the POST value after the page has displayed and before testing for the error message:

```
$tempTicketID = $_POST['ticketID'];
$_POST['ticketID'] = NULL;
```

Then testing the error message, and finally setting the POS value back before the page ends to allow it to reload correctly again:

```
$_POST['ticketID'] = $tempTicketID;
```

However the POST value doesn't save and the page reloads with no information.

Any help would be great appreciated.

Here's the full code layout:

```
##LOAD THE PAGE INFO...

#Set the temp variable and clear the post value
$tempTicketID = $_POST['ticketID'];
$_POST['ticketID'] = NULL;

#Load the form
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <strong>Add Note:</strong> 
    <textarea name="note" rows="5" cols="40" value=><?php echo htmlspecialchars($note);?></textarea>
    <span class="error">*<?php echo $noteErr;?></span><br>

    <button type='submit' name='ticketID' value= <?php echo $_POST['ticketID'];?> >View</button>
    </form>

#Test if the note is empty and the form button has been pressed
    if (!empty($_POST["note"])) 
        {
        echo "This has updated...";
        } elseif (empty($_POST["ticketID"] {
        echo "Missing!";
        }

#Set POST value back to reload the page
$_POST['ticketID'] = $tempTicketID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to restructure the form just a bit to make this happen. You can check if the form is submitted by testing for the button that *must* be clicked to submit. However, you're using that button for multiple purposes. To simplify, we'll have a separate submit button, and pass the ticketID value through the form with a hidden input. You shouldn't need the code that unsets the $_POST values.

```
<button type='submit' name='submit'> View</button>
<input type='hidden' name='ticketID' value= <?php echo $_POST['ticketID'];?> />
```

Then you can test if the form has been submitted with this quick check:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST["note"])) 
    {
        echo "This has updated...";
    } else {
        echo "Missing!";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a missing closing bracket at the end. Not sure if you want to update it for other viewers or not. I'm still relatively new to stack overflow!

Comment: Yes, always. Part of the idea here is that in the future, if someone has the same problem you had, they could find this post through a google search and harvest enough intel here that they could resolve their own problem. So yes, being thorough is always a best practice! Thanks.